# Change the pressed color of action bar item of Lollipop action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompat and have successfully implemented the new action bar that rolled out with lollipop. The only problem is the pressed background color of the action items. I want to show a different background color for the action item when pressed. Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options. But first, some background:

The action items in AppCompat use theme attribute **?attr/actionBarItemBackground** (see res/values/styles_base.xml) which is set to **?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless** (see res/styles/themes_base.xml) by default. This attribute is set to a borderless ripple on L and **@drawable/abc_item_background_holo_light** on previous versions.

The action bar itself is themed by setting **?attr/actionBarTheme** (themes_base.xml) and is set to **@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar** by default. On Holo, this theme overrides the actionBarItemBackground, so you'll need to make your changes here.

So, the easy way to override the action item background for all action bars would be to set actionBarItemBackground in your actionBarTheme. You'll probably also want to override selectableItemBackground since the CloseMode item doesn't use actionBarItemBackground (no idea why).

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/whatever_you_want</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/whatever_you_want</item>
</style>
```

**Note:** These changes apply to all API levels, so if you still want ripples on API 21+, you'll want both drawable and drawable-v21 versions of @drawable/whatever_you_want, the latter of which incorporates ripples.

Comment: @alanv How can I do this with the support Toolbar?  actionBarItemBackground and selectableItemBackground do not seem to be working when I extend Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.

Comment: @alanv Neve mind; I figured out why: I was using a custom action item.

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked:

```
    <!-- pre 21 -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selector_ab_tab_indicator</item>
    <!-- post 21 -->
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@drawable/selector_ab_tab_indicator</item>
```