# How can I change the ActionBar color with XML in Lollipop?

Tags: android

I just updated my Android SDK to 22.

When I make  an ActionBar, I’m trying to change the background, but it doesn’t work. Here’s my style.xml:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
<!--ActionBar-->
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#bf360c</item>
</style>
```

I’ve tried many times, but it always shows the dark background. What should I be doing?

Comment: Change your parent app theme to "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"..Hope it works.

Comment: Go with that..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651373/change-the-pressed-color-of-action-bar-item-of-lollipop-action-bar

Comment: @Born To Win I try ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: Android 5.0 introduces a new Toolbar widget. Try using that to customize your actionbar http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

in your activity try to do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#bf360c")));
        setContentView(R.layout.act_mainactivity);
}
```

Comment: Thx,I solve it.https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html